# 70s children's movie with a human-looking alien befriending a boy and learning Earth ways

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

It's a movie about a man that landed on Earth from space, a boy finds him and they become friends.

He is very fun and enjoys learning about living on Earth.  He appears as a human man with a funny smile and a button nose a bit over weight. At the end of the movie he leaves the Earth.

I am not sure but could it be a PBS. It aired in the 70s like about 1975.

Comment: Was this a cartoon or live-action?

Comment: Any other details? Did it take place in summer or in winter? Was any space vehicle shown?